# quartz with spring 5

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring5

We have an application which is using Spring 3 to schedule job using SimpleTruggerBean. But now we have to upgrade this to Spring 5. In Spring 5 SimpleTriggerBean has been removed and **SimpleTriggerFactoryBean** is introduced. **SimpleTriggerBean** has get/set method for JobDetail but SimpleTriggerFactoryBean has only set method.

So I am little bit confused how to change the below code in Spring 5.

```
JobDetail jobDetails = ticketTrigger.getJobDetail();
jobDetails.setName(JOB_NAME);
jobDetails.setGroup(JOB_GROUP);
```

**Bean details**

```
<bean id="methodTicketJob" class="org.psringframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailsFactoryBean">
<property name="targetObject" value="ticketJob" />
<property name="targetMethod" value="export" />
<property name="concurrent" value="flase" />
</bean>

<bean id=""ticketTrigger" class="org.psringframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
<property name="jobDetail" ref="methodTicketJob" />
<property name="repeatInterval" value="1000000" />
</bean>
```

can you please how I can achieve this ?

Comment: where do you want to set name and group? In executing job bean?

Comment: @Nagaraddi yes, there we are adding the job to the scheduler after setting all these details

Comment: Why not set name and group name on MethodInvokingJobDetailsFactoryBean configuration itself?

Comment: @Nagaraddi there some condition based on which it will pick up the name and group, so we are not setting it there while creating the bean. I am not sure why Spring 5 have the setter method for jobDetails but not the getter. so is there a way we can get the job details and then set the name/group